# Match date in dd-MMM-yy format to yyyy-MM-dd in Hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, impala

I have this date `01-APR-04` but I have to do the following operation

`01-APR-04 >(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),1) AS STRING),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))`,

How could I convert `01-APR-04` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert '01-APR-04' to 'yyyy-MM-dd' using unix_timestamp+from_unixtime to be able to compare with date:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01-APR-04','dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') >
       date_sub(current_date(),1) -- returns false
```